# How to remove space between rows in MathJax? (Clean checkerboard pattern?)

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm trying to draw a checkerboard (chessboard) pattern, but there is a problem.

Is it possible to draw it, such that there is no space at all, between rows and columns?

Failed attempt one: (rows and columns are spaced)

$$
\begin{array}{}
\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}&\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}&\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\\
\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}&\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}&\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\\
\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}&\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}&\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}
\end{array}
$$

Failed attempt two: (rows are spaced)

$$\begin{aligned}{}
\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\\[-5mm]
\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\\[-5mm]
\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\color{magenta}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\color{black}{\Rule{5mm}{5mm}{0mm}}
\end{aligned}$$

> How to remove space between rows?

Comment: What's the end goal of this exercise?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Visualizing a specific family of matrices, where instead of integers, we use colors. (I know I can simply include a image of the visualization, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do it directly in MathJax for small matrices.)

Comment: MathJax is meant to render and communicate mathematical content in a meaningful way---unlike TeX, it is not a typesetting program, and is not meant to be used for page layout functionality.  I think that you are probably better off using an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not perfect, but hopefully close to what you want:

$$\begin{aligned}{} 
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em] 
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em]
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\begin{aligned}{} 
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em] 
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em]
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em] 
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\end{aligned}
$$

```
$$\begin{aligned}{} 
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em] 
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em]
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\begin{aligned}{} 
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em] 
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em]
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{1mm}}\\[-1em] 
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{magenta}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\color{black}{\Rule{10mm}{10mm}{0mm}}
\end{aligned}
$$
```